# Using ifelse to install a package

Tags: r

I've tried to create a "shortcut" that checks if a package is installed and naturally thought of going for `ifelse`. 
Below is a reproducible example:

```
ifelse(!"tree"%in%names(installed.packages()),install.packages("tree"),library(tree))
```

**EDIT::**

The package is downloaded but I still get this error presumably because the above continues to be called somehow.

> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
>     replacement has length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
>     'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

The above appears to work except after downloading the package, an error is returned that I can't seem to figure out exactly how to solve:

I could use a different way to achieve the same but would really love to know what's going on here.
Thanks!

Comment: `ifelse()` will evaluate all of its parameters and try to return a vector the same length as the input. It's not really appropriate in this case (conditional execution). You should use a standard `if/else` expression.

Comment: `names(installed.packages())` returns `NULL`, you can get the package names with `rownames()`

Comment: @MrFlick makes sense. Thanks!