# How to make R install required packages?

Tags: r

I work on a group project. For my analyses, I need a few packages. So in order to let my script work on everyones computer I tell R at the beginning to check for the name of the required package among all installed packages, and, if the name is not there, install it. My code is:

```
{
ifelse("ggplot2" %in% rownames(installed.packages()),"" ,install.packages("ggplot2"))
ifelse("agricolae" %in% rownames(installed.packages()),"" ,install.packages("agricolae"))
ifelse("lattice" %in% rownames(installed.packages()),"" ,install.packages("lattice"))
ifelse("DescTools" %in% rownames(installed.packages()),"" ,install.packages("DescTools"))
ifelse("FSA" %in% rownames(installed.packages()),"" ,install.packages("FSA")) }
```

But it seems to work not quite good. Like, R installes the first, but not the second.
Is it just because ggplot is too huge and R forgetsthe rest or do I have another mistake?

Thank you all ahead!

Comment: 1- create a vector of package names. 2- create a function. 3- run the function over the vector. e.g.: `x <- c("ggplot2", "lattice") ; f <- function(x) if(!x %in% rownames(installed.packages())) install.packages(x) ; lapply(x, f)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771441/using-ifelse-to-install-a-package

Answer (score 5):

It think the reason you're confused is that you've put all those commands in a braced code block, which will only return 1 thing. If you just removed the braces it might be a little more clear. Observe:

```
{
    ifelse(TRUE, "yes", "no")
    ifelse(TRUE, "yes", "no")
}
Returns: "yes"
```

Only one. Even better, try this:

```
packages=c("ggplot2", "lattice", "simpleCache")

installed = rownames(installed.packages())

for (pkg in packages) {
    if (! pkg %in% installed) {
        install.packages(pkg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is not the reason. Reason is the  invisible `NULL` of `install.packages` together with the use of `ifelse` instead of `if`. In the end the OP is anyways not interested in any return value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `ifelse`. From the help of  `ifelse`:

> ‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’ which is
>        filled with elements selected from either ‘yes’ or ‘no’ depending
>        on whether the element of ‘test’ is ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’.

Now `install.packages` returns `NULL` invisibly and this does not work with `ifelse` as you can see:

```
ifelse(T, NULL, 1)
# Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
# replacement has length zero
# In addition: Warning message:
# In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
#   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

`ifelse` is intended to be used with vectors for example:

```
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 1, 2))
# [1] 1 2 1
```

and does thus not cope well with the `NULL` value returned by `install.packages`.

What you want as an one-to-one replacement of your code would be something like:

```
if ("ggplot2" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) install.packages("ggplot2")
```

But it is better to use one of the `list` based answers you got here, because it is much easier to maintain.